# Support Rust language syntax highlighting on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Support proper syntax highlighting for code sections containing [Rust](http://www.rust-lang.org) code.

Comment: Yup, it's pretty simple - the solution is to write a rust module for prettify.js, and SO will get it eventually too.

Comment: What's Rust? How many questions are there tagged with it? How many of those actually have code in them? (Answers: an exotic not often used language, 90 questions tagged, less than 90 actually have code). Probably doesn't qualify for syntax highlighting.